# ReactJS export functions to use in other files

Tags: reactjs

So I am building a ReactJS website/app and getting to grips with things. I am trying to have multiple re-usable components of code (to save me time) and to get used to it I have made this placeholder component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import '../App.css';

const PlaceholderImage = () => (
    <Image src="../images/wip.gif" fluid/>
)

export const PlaceholderImage;
```

And I am trying to call it in another page like so...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PlaceholderImage } from '../components/placeholder';
import '../App.css';

class App extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <PlaceholderImage/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Both files are within my src folder, but my components are held in the components folder and the pages are held within my routes folder.

When I try to build this with yarn, i get the unexpected token errors on the semi colon. I have tried other methods of exporting like

```
export default PlaceholderImage;
export () => PlaceholderImage;
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `PlaceholderImage` twice with const

Try:

```
const PlaceholderImage = () => (
    <Image src="../images/wip.gif" fluid/>
)

export default PlaceholderImage;
```

And

```
import PlaceholderImage from '../components/placeholder'; // without brackets
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default PlaceholderImage;

import PlaceholderImage from '../components/placeholder'; // without {}
```